# Javascript Array with number as property name

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
var myArray = new Array(); 
myArray['112'] = 0;
myArray.length
```

Why is `length` 113 in above sample? Shouldn't `'112'` add a object property for the array and create something similar to `myArray = {"112":0}`?

Besides this, why is the length 113 and not 1? Since `myArray` actually only contains 1 value

Comment: pshhhh....That's surprising. Learn something new everyday.

Comment: Because the length is always set to the largest positive integer property name plus one. The array only has one enumerable property, but it has a length of 113 (see ECMA-262 15.4).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider this simple example:

```
var aa = [];
aa[3] = 'three';
alert( aa.length // 4
  + '\n' + aa[2]    // undefined 
  + '\n' + aa.hasOwnProperty('2') // false
);
```

The number *3* is used to assign the property name, but it is converted to a string and used as a standard property name (i.e. the string "3").

Adding a property named "3" has created one property and set the length to 4 since the length is always set to one more than the largest non-negative integer property name.

No other property is created, the array is "sparse", i.e. it doesn't have sequentially named (numbered) members. A *for..in* loop can also be used to see that there is only one property.

Comment: So `var aa=[]` `aa[0] = 'zero';` `aa[1] = 'one';` gets converted to `var aa = {'0':'zero', '1' : 'one'}` by the interpreter?

Comment: More or less, but remember that Arrays inherit from *Array.prototype* and have a special *length* property so they are a bit more sophisticated than plain objects. But underneath, they are just objects. Oh, and number property names being converted to strings is part of how Objects work that also applies to Arrays, it's not specific to Arrays.

Answer (score 4):

The array `length` is one more than the highest index, so you get `113`.

Comment: Well, to be clear, the interface isn't sparse.  It may be internally, depending on the values stored.

Comment: @MatthewFlaschen: Yeah sorry, I just went to ninja edit but looks like someone had already noticed :P

Comment: Arrays only have sequentially numbered indexes if you give them sequentially numbered indexes. The OP's example is a case where they aren't sequential. The array only has one enumerable property named '112'. Length is set automatically to the largest positive integer property name plus one (so is set to '113').

Comment: @RobG: I see. Why does `console.log()` print out a bunch of `undefined`? I see `Object.keys()` shows the only enumerable property. What would I change to my answer if it's wrong?

Comment: Remove "sequentially" from the first sentence, and the phrase "and are sparse" (sparse is a concept of indexes not being sequential, so it might be a property of an instance, not arrays in general). Remove the second sentence entirely, the allocation of a particular index doesn't cause all lower indexes to be created as properties (as for..in iteration will reveal). Attempting to access missing properties returns *undefined*, *hasOwnProperty* will return false (though in some browsers attempting to access missing indexes causes them to be added as properties, but they are still undefined).

Comment: @RobG: Hehe, that's a long way to say "can it all except the last sentence". I really need to stop putting off reading the Ecma spec in its entirety.

Comment: I've not read the spec end to end, I find it easier to swallow in bits, though I think I've read every section. It takes a while to grok, I had to actually *learn* it, otherwise it didn't seem to sink in.

Answer (score 2):

No. The `'112'` string and a pure numeric `112` evaluate to the same thing when JS is doing the array lookup, so you get a slot in the array rather than a property.

Simplest to think of a JS Array indexes as properties that happen to be numbers, even in string form. It's more chameleonic than you'd think at first.

But if you add a property with some nonnumeric name, like `myArray['foo']`, it will do as you expect and the length won't change.

Comment: A "slot in an array" is a property. All array property names are strings, even if a number is used in the assignment (it is converted to a string). Arrays are just objects with a special length property. The length is always one greater than the largest positive integer property name.

Comment: You have it backwards. As crazy as it sounds, all array indexes *are* actually string properties, as opposed to numeric indexes, according to the ECMAScript specs.

Answer (score -2):

You got array of `0..112` elements - in total length of 113 elements.